# How to connect to a database project?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, tfs, msdeploy

I have a team working on a project.  For the purpose of collaboration we are using `Team Foundation Server`.

Now we want to create a shared database so that each team member can connect to the database, manipulate it, and retrieve data.

I've already created a `SQL Database Project` and I've added it to TFS but I don't know how to connect to it from my code ?

Comment: Haven't worked with TFS, but doesn't it work like with any other [SQL Server](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)?

Comment: @Corak: TFS isn't a SQL Server.  It's the source control source.  Yes, it's backed by SQL server but that isn't really what the OPs question is about.

Comment: @ChrisLively: TFS is definitely more than just source control.  (Though I don't consider it to be very good at any of the many things it does.)  It is, however, backed by a SQL database.  Though one should never need or want to directly manipulate that data... it's just asking for trouble with TFS.

Comment: @David: of course it's more than just source.  TFS is simply unrelated to what the OP is doing.

Comment: @ChrisLively: On that we agree.  His terminology was clouding his question.

Comment: @David: I updated the question for the OP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SQL Database Project is just a representation of the database schema and objects.  It isn't a database that you "connect to".

Instead you will need a SQL server running somewhere.  You might decide to run it locally on each of your dev machines or have a common server that everyone accesses.  Either way, a regular SQL server needs to be installed somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for this very useful answer. So, we need a SQL Server host.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't have anything to do with TFS.  This is just a Visual Studio project like any other.

What exactly do you mean by "connect to it from my code"?  .NET code doesn't directly interact with a database *project*, but can form a data access layer to interact with a *database*.

If you right-click on the database project in Visual Studio, there is an option to deploy (or perhaps publish, depending on the Visual Studio version).  You can deploy the database project to a live database and then your .NET code can interact with that database.

This can be multiple databases.  For example, your automated builds can deploy to a shared database for everyone to use, and individual developers can deploy to their local workstations for development and debugging purposes.

Comment: Thank you very much. This was very helpful. I think we need a host. Any suggestions?

Comment: @user2791233: Depends on your environment.  If everybody's on the same LAN then you can just add a server to the LAN and install SQL Server on it.  (Express edition is free, if you don't have a SQL Server license.)  Individual workstations can also have SQL Server installed.  If you're distributed over the internet, that could be a challenge.  VPN to a central LAN?  Open a central SQL Server to the internet?  Pay for a hosting service?  Windows Azure?  At that point you question whether the benefits of a shared host outweigh the challenge of having one.

Comment: I really apreciate your answer. Thank you so much again. Will think about what I need to do.

Answer (score 1):

The Sql Database project is not a database in itself - it is a project that describes a database. You need to deploy that project (typically to an instance of Sql Server) in order to connect to it in the way you describe.

In a typical team development environment, each member of your team might have their own local instance of Sql Server, and deploy the project to it. In this way, your team members won't get in eachother's way as they create and delete data during the course of development. You will possibly also want a shared instance for a more formal testing environment.

So ultimately, what you've created is not a shared database: it's a template that a database can be created from.

Comment: That is what I need. A shared database that can be altered by anyone of the team members. Any suggestion?

Comment: Simply install Sql server on a shared machine and deploy your project there.

Comment: We are distributed over the internet, not in the same LAN.

Comment: Then you either need an internet-accessible shared server, or to each install Sql and deploy the database locally.